# Change an atomic value in an XML file using the Php XML DOM

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to learn how to use the Php XML DOM in order to access an XML file and 
change the an atomic value. I haven't done something like this before and although I found many similar cases online, I haven't managed to find a solution.
This is what I have:

```
  <?php
   $dom = new DOMDocument;
   $dom->load('getobs.xml');

   $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
   $nodeList = $xpath->query("//beginPosition");
   $nodeList->item(0)->nodeValue .= '546';

   $dom->saveXML();
   ?>
```

So, what I am trying to do in the above code is to:
 1) load an xml file.
 2) change the value of the element "beginPosition" to '546'

In the whole XML file there is only one element with this name (beginPosition).
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.
Dimtris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to do it by using the following code:

```
    <?php
    // create new DOM document and load the data
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->load('getobs.xml');
    //var_dump($dom);
    // Create new xpath and register the namespace
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('g','http://www.opengis.net/gml');
    // query the result amd change the value to the new date
    $result = $xpath->query("//g:beginPosition");
    $result->item(0)->nodeValue = 'sds';
    // save the values in a new xml
    file_put_contents('test.xml',$dom->saveXML());
    ?>
```

The mistake is that I wasn't registering the namespace!

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the result back to the file. `saveXML()` is a badly named method, it returns the result as xml, it does not save it back to the file.

[saveXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php)

Change the last line to

```
 file_put_contents('getobs.xml',$dom->saveXML());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still it doesn't work. Can it be related with the namespaces? Should I use the registerNamespace function?